# what is relationship between of Proxy timeouts, keepalive timeouts in nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I am pretty new to nginx I have confusion between keepalive_timeout, proxy_read_timeout, proxy_send_timout, and proxy_connect_timeout.

I want to configure nginx so the idle connection should close immediately but if a request is forwarded upstream or if a sub-request is sent the nginx should wait for a long time for response.